# How to prove $\lim_{n \to \infty} \big(\text{sin}(\frac{1}{n+1})+...+\text{sin}(\frac{1}{2n}) \big)$ exists?

Tags: analysis

Could anyone advise me on how to prove  $\lim_{n \to \infty} \big(\text{sin}(\frac{1}{n+1})+...+\text{sin}(\frac{1}{2n}) \big)$ exists  ?

My attempt: Since $\ a_n = \ n\text{sin}(\frac{1}{2n}) \leq\text{sin}(\frac{1}{n+1})+...+\text{sin}(\frac{1}{2n}) \leq n\text{sin}(\frac{1}{n}) = b_n,$ for sufficiently large $n$ and $(a_n) , \ (b_n)$ are convergent sequences, we can try prove that  $\big(\text{sin}(\frac{1}{n+1})+...+\text{sin}(\frac{1}{2n})\big)$ is monotone?

Thank you.

Comment: $\sin x = x+ \mathcal{O}(x^3)$, so $\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{2n} \sin \frac{1}{k} = \sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac{1}{k}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$, and $\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac{1}{k} \to \log 2$ as $n \to \infty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the well known inequalities for sin. 
$$\text{sin}(x) \leq x$$ for $x\geq 0$, 
and
$$\text{sin}(x) \geq x - x^2/\pi$$ for $0\leq x \leq \pi$.

$$\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac{1}{k} \to \log 2$$
$$\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac{1}{k^2} \to 0$$

Then you have the sandwich theorem.

Comment: You might want to note the limit evaluates to ln 2 by using Riemann Sums.

Answer (score 1):

You may also use $$1+\frac{4-2\pi}{\pi^2}x\leq \frac{\sin x}{x} \leq \frac{4}{\pi}-\frac{4}{\pi^2}x$$ for $0<x\leq \pi/2$.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that $\sin (x)$ is a monotonic increasing function on the particular domain of interest $(0,1]$.

Secondly, note that $\sin(x) < x$ in the same domain.

So, we start studying the convergence of this serie:

$a_n = \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n+1} ... + \frac{1}{2n}$.

We have

$a_{n+1} - a_n = \frac{1}{2n+1} + \frac{1}{2n+2} - \frac{1}{n} < \frac{1}{2n} + \frac{1}{2n} - \frac{1}{n} = 0$. 
So this sequence is **decreasing**, and obviously bounded inferiorly by zero, so convergent.

Now, let's give no chance to your sequence to escape:

$c_n = \sin(\frac{1}{n+1}) + \sin(\frac{1}{n+2}) ... + \sin(\frac{1}{2n})$.

It is crescent, since

$c_{n+1} - c_n = \sin(\frac{1}{2n+1}) + \sin(\frac{1}{2n+2}) - \sin(\frac{1}{n+1}) = \sin(\frac{1}{2n+1}) + \sin(\frac{1}{2n+2}) - \sin(\frac{1}{2n+2} + \frac{1}{2n+2}) > 2 \sin(\frac{1}{2n+2}) - 2\sin(\frac{1}{2n+2}) \cos(\frac{1}{2n+2}) > 0$

But since is limited by $\lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n$, is convergent.